# How to display the user's username on profile from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

My problem is that when users save their information(username), it has to go on their profile.

The saving information when signing up works, their data goes to Firebase. I tried a lot of tutorials but nothing seems to work. Here is the code for the signing up:

```
 private fun saveUserInfo(fullName: String, userName: String, email: String, progressDialog: ProgressDialog)
{
    val currentUserID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
    val usersRef: DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users")

    val userMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
    userMap["uid"] = currentUserID
    userMap["fullname"] = fullName.toLowerCase()
    userMap["username"] = userName.toLowerCase()
    userMap["email"] = email
   

    usersRef.child(currentUserID).setValue(userMap)
        .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful)
            {
                progressDialog.dismiss()
                Toast.makeText(this, "Account has been created successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                val intent = Intent(this@SignUpActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                startActivity(intent)
                finish()
            }
            else
            {
                val message = task.exception!!.toString()
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error: $message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
                progressDialog.dismiss()
            }
        }
```

The Profile fragment contains a "username" TextView, which I want to get replaced with the user's actual userna,e. If someone has any idea, I'd be glad to know.

Comment: "nothing seems to work" is really hard to help with. I don't immediately see any obvious error in the code you shared, so it's probably if you debug locally and tell us the results of that. If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: If you're new to debugging on Android, the Android docs have a great page on [debugging your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug) to get you started with, including the section on [working with breakpoints](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#breakPoints) and [inspecting varialbles](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#variablesAndWatches).

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Answer (score 0):

```
private fun getProfileDetails(){
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(firebaseAuth.currentUser!!.uid).
        addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object :ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                username = snapshot.child("userName").value as String
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }
        })
}
```

you can use coroutines in your code to get the data asynchronously. Call this function whenever the user opens up the profile activity or fragment